# Rename the keys of an imported array on a single line (much like destructuring)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In javascript and React Native, I use an API function which returns two elements: `results` and `error`.

```
import { findAll as forumFindAll } from '../../Api/ForumApi'

const IndexScreen = () => {
    const [results, error] = forumFindAll()
    ...
```

I would like to rename the variables `results` and `error` on a single line (much like destructuring).

Something like that (but I know it doesn't work) :

```
const [results as forumsResults, error as forumsError] = forumFindAll()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since `forumFindAll` returns an array, there should be no need to "rename" any of its items - simply put in the names you want into the destructuring syntax:

```
const [forumsResults, forumsError] = forumFindAll();
```

The return value of `forumFindAll` does not have any intrinsic connection to the `results` and `error` names, you can choose whatever names you wish.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very simple !